# Looking for fast and possibile free pre-os

Tags: boot, operating-systems

I am looking for a **preos** that I can install in dual boot with Windows XP and that can me allow to switch on my PC and be ready in few seconds.

I would like to have this features

- Browse internet (mail, surfing, ecc.)
- Chart and IM capabilities (Skype)
- See images
- See videos
- Listen to music

Windows is not free, therefore I imagine I should move to Linux.

What do you suggest?

Comment: I'd like for someone with Archlinux experience to answer.  It has a minimalist approach but allows for easy extension.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Archlinux and it is quite fast if set up correctly. I don't think its "a few seconds" fast though.

Comment: "Grub to GUI in 16 seconds" he says: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRK9InfGwcE.  And this guy, 26 seconds from power-on to Firefox: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzqSjAoQvxM (SSD, though).

Answer (score 1):

If you can find Windows 3.1 and some software for it, I suppose it'll be fast enough. Windows 98 should also be quite fast on a modern PC.

On the Linux side, you're probably looking at [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/), which you can even boot from a usb pen drive.
This is reproduced from their site:

> DSL has a nearly complete desktop, and
>   a tiny core of command line tools. All
>   applications are chosen with the best
>   balance of functionality, size and
>   speed. Damn Small also has the ability
>   to act as an SSH/FTP/HTTPD server
>   right off of a live CD. In our quest
>   to save space and have a fully
>   functional desktop we've made many GUI
>   administration tools which are fast
>   yet still easy to use. What does DSL
>   have?
>
> XMMS (MP3, CD Music, and MPEG), FTP
>   client, Dillo web browser, Netrik web
>   browser, FireFox, spreadsheet,
>   Sylpheed email, spellcheck (US
>   English), a word-processor (Ted),
>   three editors (Beaver, Vim, and Nano
>   [Pico clone]), graphics editing and
>   viewing (Xpaint, and xzgv), Xpdf (PDF
>   Viewer), emelFM (file manager), Naim
>   (AIM, ICQ, IRC), VNCviwer, Rdesktop,
>   SSH/SCP server and client, DHCP
>   client, PPP, PPPoE (ADSL), a web
>   server, calculator, generic and
>   GhostScript printer support, NFS,
>   Fluxbox and JWM window managers,
>   games, system monitoring apps, a host
>   of command line tools, USB support,
>   and pcmcia support, some wireless
>   support.

You can still extend DSL easily using the [Damn Small Linux myDSL Application Extensions](http://distro.ibiblio.org/pub/linux/distributions/damnsmall/mydsl/).
Although I've never used DSL, I'm a great admirer of this project.

Comment: Does Skype run on Windows 3.1? :)

Comment: Apparently it did once - http://www.dvhardware.net/software/8084. I doubt that the latest version does.